kubelogin on WSL Centos: sudo az aks install-cli: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend'
Trying to install az kubelogin on WSL Centos:
sudo az aks install-cli --debug:

az_command_data_logger: No module named '_cffi_backend'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 231, in invoke
cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
File "/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/init.py", line 561, in execute
self.commands_loader.load_arguments(command)
File "/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/init.py", line 515, in load_arguments
self.command_table[command].load_arguments()  # this loads the arguments via reflection
File "/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/init.py", line 318, in load_arguments
super(AzCliCommand, self).load_arguments()
File "/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/commands.py", line 104, in load_arguments
cmd_args = self.arguments_loader()
File "/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py", line 125, in arguments_loader
op = self.get_op_handler(self.op_path)
File "/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py", line 59, in get_op_handler
handler = import_module(mod_to_import)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/importlib/init.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import
File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "", line 850, in exec_module
File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/custom.py", line 37, in 
from azure.cli.command_modules.acs import acs_client, proxy
File "/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/acs_client.py", line 13, in 
import paramiko
File "/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/init.py", line 22, in 
from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
File "/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 91, in 
from paramiko.dsskey import DSSKey
File "/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/dsskey.py", line 37, in 
from paramiko.pkey import PKey
File "/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 31, in 
import bcrypt
File "/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bcrypt/init.py", line 25, in 
from . import _bcrypt  # type: ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend'

Solution:
sudo yum install -y python3-cffi.x86_64
fixed the problem
